# Using replace to remove <strong> tags from html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `innerHTML` methid to retrieve the innerHTML from a `div`. There can be multiple instances of `<strong>` `</strong>` throughout the string

I am doing something like this to replace the `strong tag

```
inpStr=this.innerHTML 

inpStr=this.innerHTML.replace('<strong>','').replace('</strong>','')
```

However, this only replaces the first occerance of strong tag. I am not very familiar with regex but I read about using `/g` to replace all occurrence but it does not work either.

```
inpStr=this.innerHTML.replace('/<strong>/g','').replace('/<//strong>/g','')
```

Changing to above code does not work at all and does not replace anything at all, not even the first instance. Also I am using the double // in `/<//strong>/g',''` to escape the closing tag in strong but I am not sure.

Comment: use `/<\/strong>/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` otherwise JavaScript thinks you closed your Regular Expression.  Do that with a `\`.  So `/<\/strong>/g`.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const foo = document.getElementById("foo");
  foo.innerHTML = foo
    .innerHTML
    .replace(/<strong>/g, "")
    .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "");
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
  <strong>foo</strong>
</div>

<button id="button">Weaken</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You're not escaping properly, i.e `\/` not `//`
2. you can use optional character i.e `\/?`

---

```
inpStr=this.innerHTML.replace('/<\/?strong>/g','')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function

```
const replaceAll = (word, search, replacement) => {
    return word.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```